# Implementing Bootstrap makes the font size scaled down

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I made a CSS file for the web at first but now that I want to implement Bootstrap in the middle of the development, I added the Bootstrap CDN into the HTML file. But it seems to be scaling down my `font-size` for the whole thing.

**BEFORE**

[image: BEFORE]

**AFTER**

[image: AFTER]

What should I do to make it back to what it was without using `!important` to the `font-size` of every class in the CSS?

Comment: Please post a [example].

Comment: @Kameron I don't really know what code should I put in here. The only difference is the presence of Bootstrap in the HTML file. What suggestion do you have for me to provide you with so you can understand this question better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/content/typography/#:%7E:text=In%20Bootstrap%205%2C%20we%27ve,across%20device%20and%20viewport%20sizes.),

> In Bootstrap 5, we’ve enabled responsive font sizes by default, allowing text to scale more naturally across device and viewport sizes.

For more info about Bootstrap’s resizing engine, I recommend reading the [following article](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/getting-started/rfs/).

> What should I do to make it back to what it was without using !important to the font-size of every class in the CSS?

To override it, you can try the following:

```
html {
  font-size: 20px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you import the bootstrap link after your css file import? if yes then import bs first then import your custom css.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
```

bcz I'm guessing that bs typo class is overwriting your custom css class.

Comment: Yes, I already have done that but it seems there is something that BS has but my CSS doesn't have thus making things look like this.

Comment: is there any custom class in your text container tag ?

Comment: Haki is not font related issue. If u see closely then u can see every element is scaled down (your cards, Your search bar , side nav). In your head is there `<meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` this meta exist ?

Comment: No class in the text container tag. Yes, the meta is in the head.

Comment: exactly this meta ? `<meta charset="utf-8">   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">`

Comment: Yup, `<meta charset="UTF-8" /><meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />`

Answer (score -1):

You could add additional font-size in your CSS but ensure your custom CSS file is loaded after the Bootstrap CSS.

Use a higher percentage if you like but going below 100% will make the font even smaller.

```
body{
font-size: 110%;
}
```